# alignment of numbers in exponential format in a table with complicated header rows

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I have a table that contains a lot of numbers. I have been defining new column types to allow me to specify column widths and allow `\newline` within a cell. Some of my columns of numbers are in exponential format. I previously had these as text, like "0.496E+07" but to be consistent with the rest of the document, I have just converted them to `\num{0.496e7}` using `siunitx`. The problem is that now the numbers are not aligned.

I am unsure how I could use the `S` column type because I don't know how to redefine it with a width as I have with `R{width}` for `r` for example.

I tried using `\tablenum` but everything scoots out of the RHS of the table column, and I can't work out whether I can fix that using `table-format`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, fleqn]{report}

% Page geometry etc
%----------------------------
\usepackage{setspace}                % allow different line spacing
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\usepackage[showframe,top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, includehead]{geometry}
\geometry{headheight=28pt, headsep=18pt}

% Maths stuff
%------------
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\centering\textbf{#1}}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.11cm}


\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing


\begin{table}
\centering 
\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{|L{3.2cm} || r | R{2.0cm}  | r| R{1.1cm} || r | R{2.0cm}| r  | R{1.1cm} | }
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{ } &  \multicolumn{4}{ c ||}{\textbf{Full Selection}} & \multicolumn{4}{ c |}{\textbf{Max Condition Number $\mathbf{10^6}$}}\tabularnewline  \cline{2-9}  
 \head{Method and Details}   & \head{NCh}   & \head{Condition Number} & \head{DFS} & \head{DFS\newline per chan}  & \head{NCh} & \head{Condition Number} & \head{DFS} & \head{DFS\newline per chan} \tabularnewline [0.5ex]
  \hline
  \textbf{1:}             &     210 & \num{0.496E+07} &  84.3  &   0.40   &    153 &     \num{0.8126E+06} &  69.3   &   0.45 \\ 
  \textbf{2:}  8 Clear 1.3 WVE       &     183 & \num{0.130E+11} & 207.1  &   1.13   &     76 &     \num{0.9469E+06} &  91.5   &   1.20 \\ [1ex] 
  % [1ex] adds vertical space

  \hline 
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{caption }

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Here's what the output looks like, note the lack of alignment in column 3:

[image: table]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, any table that uses `\multirow` can immediately improved by removing it.

Use the features in `siunitx`, which go much beyond `\num`. As you see, you have to do just one measurement: the tabular, without the local setting of `\tabcolsep` is overfull by 9.52791pt, so I just cut off the necessary space doing a simple division. The exact result is .595494375pt, but 0.6 is just as good.

Please, avoid single vertical rules and abhor double vertical rules.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=2.5cm,
  left=3.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  includehead,
  headheight=28pt,
  headsep=18pt,
  showframe,
}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\centering 
\footnotesize
%%% Without the following, the overfull is 9.52791pt;
%%% since there are nine columns and so 16 intercolumn
%%% spaces, do 9.52791/16=0.6
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.6pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=1.3e2]
  S[table-format=3.1]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=1.4e2]
  S[table-format=3.1]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Full Selection} &
   \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries\boldmath Max Condition Number $10^6$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9} % no "r" here because it's the last column
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{Method and \\ Details}} &
  \head{NCh} & \head{Condition \\ Number} & \head{DFS} & \head{DFS \\ per \\ chan} &
  \head{NCh} & \head{Condition \\ Number} & \head{DFS} & \head{DFS \\ per \\ chan} \\
\midrule
\textbf{1:}                 & 210 & 0.496E+07 &  84.3 & 0.40 & 153 & 0.8126E+06 & 69.3 & 0.45 \\ 
\textbf{2:} 8 Clear 1.3 WVE & 183 & 0.130E+11 & 207.1 & 1.13 &  76 & 0.9469E+06 & 91.5 & 1.20 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{caption}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's amazing!. Obviously I knew it was a mess, but I had no idea I could remove so much. Thanks also for the pretty comprehensive list of what `table-format` can do. I notice everyone round here hates vertical rules - I think I'm a bit old-fashioned, I 'grew up' producing excel tables in the '90's :-)

Comment: One quick question: best to check, presumably the change to `tabcolsep` remains within this table environment?

Comment: @FionaSmith Boxing cells is useful when looking at a worksheet; not at all when looking at a typeset table. Yes, the setting to `\tabcolsep` is only in the table environment. I don't think it's a good thing to set it globally in the preamble. Not to 1.1mm, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use two different column types *simultaneously* for a tabular column, e.g., both an `S` column (with suitably set options, see below) to typeset numerical entries in scientific/exponential format *and* something like

```
\multicolumn{1}{R{2.0cm}|}{...}
```

to typeset the information in the two corresponding header cells. Note that you should eliminate the `\num` wrappers from the numbers in question. I would also get rid of the double vertical lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, fleqn]{report}

% Page geometry etc
\usepackage{setspace} % allow different line spacing
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\usepackage[showframe,top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, includehead]{geometry}
\geometry{headheight=28pt, headsep=18pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}
%%\usepackage{multirow} % not needed
%%\usepackage{array}    % not needed

% tabular stuff
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\centering\textbf{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.11cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=left,
         tight-spacing = true}
\centering
\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{|L{3.2cm} | 
  r | S[table-format = +1.3e+2] | r | R{1.1cm} | 
  r | S[table-format = +1.4e+2] | r | R{1.1cm} | }  
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{ c |}{\head{Full Selection}} 
  & \multicolumn{4}{ c |}{\head{Max Condition Number $\mathbf{10^6}$}} \tabularnewline  
  \cline{2-9}
  \head{Method and Details}   & 
  \head{NCh} & \multicolumn{1}{R{2.0cm}|}{\head{Condition Number}} & \head{DFS} & \head{DFS\newline per chan}  &
  \head{NCh} & \multicolumn{1}{R{2.0cm}|}{\head{Condition Number}} & \head{DFS} & \head{DFS\newline per chan} \tabularnewline [0.5ex]
  \hline
  \textbf{1:}  &     210 & 0.496e07 &  84.3  &   0.40   &    153 &     0.8126E+06 &  69.3   &   0.45 \\
  \textbf{2:}  8 Clear 1.3 WVE       &     183 & 0.130E11 & 207.1  &   1.13   &     76 &   0.9469E6 &  91.5   &   1.20 \\ [1ex]
  % [1ex] adds vertical space
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{caption }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. It's very useful to know that.