# single table cell out of vertical alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Having been guided by the wisdom of those more experienced than me, I have been using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179998/19440) to my previous question to change all my tables into ones that look better using `booktabs`. One of my tables is giving me some grief. The vertical alignment of one of my header row cells is off, and I have no idea why.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=2.5cm,
  left=3.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  includehead,
  headheight=28pt,
  headsep=18pt,
  showframe,
}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} 

\newcommand{\headrow}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ l L{5cm} L{3cm} L{3.5cm} }
    \toprule
          & \headrow{Instrument Name}  & \headrow{Instrument Type} & \headrow{Main Purpose} \\
    \midrule
    IASI  & Infrared Atmospheric Sounding Interferometer & IR interferometer & Atmospheric temperature and humidity profiles; trace gases \\
    AMSU  & Advanced Microwave Sounding Unit & Microwave radiometer & Atmospheric temperature \\
    MHS   & Microwave Humidity Sounder       & Microwave radiometer & Atmospheric humidity    \\

    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My table of instruments}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Gives the following output. Why is the middle one bottom aligned?

[image: tbale]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just playing with your MWE shows that the column seems to be too narrow. Allowing more space for the second column aligns it to the top again.

Unfortunately I don't know why this happens, but it gives you the opportunity to fix the issue by enlarging the column to 3.1cm.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Very odd. I'm surprised I didn't stumble across that solution myself - I almost gave it some extra width anyway a few seconds ago! Well, easily fixed anyway, thanks for having a play!